# Linq Statement when you need to do a Convert.To?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there anyways I can stop from having to stay Convert twice?

```
allObjects.Where(x => 
  Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDate).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
  Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDate).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToList()
```

Assume I can't change the type of "MyDate" to datetime to stop from having to do the convert in the first place

Comment: You could project using `select` before the where in order to do the conversion ahead of time, but you might need to undo via another select after (depending on your need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a helper extension method will make your query more readable:

```
static class DayOfWeekExtensions {
    public static bool IsWeekEnd(DayOfWeek dow) {
        return dow == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dow == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    }
}
```

Now your query could be rewritten as follows:

```
var notOnWeekEnds = allObjects
    .Where(x => !Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDate).DayOfWeek.IsWeekEnd())
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

For these sorts of cases it is often easier to use the query comprehension form.

```
var q = from obj in allObjects
        let day = Convert.ToDateTime(obj.MyDate).DayOfWeek
        where day != DayOfWeek.Saturday
        where day != DayOfWeek.Sunday
        select obj;
var result = q.ToList();
```

Note that the answer given by Tim Schmelter is the fluent form of this query; I find the comprehension form much easier to read and reason about.

Comment: 1000 times yes.

Answer (score 2):

> Assume I can't change the type of "MyDate" to datetime to stop from
>   having to do the convert in the first place

Why you assume that? That would be the best option

If you can't do that you could store the result in an anonymous type:

```
var objectList = allObjects
   .Select(x => new { Object = x, Date = Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDate) })
   .Where(x => x.Date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.Date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
   .Select(x => x.Object)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: In C# 7 you could also use a value tuple instead of an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
allObject.Where(x => { var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDate);
                       return dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday;
                     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes -

```
allObjects.Where(x => {
     var dateConvered = Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDate);
     return dateConvered .DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && dateConvered.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday; }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go this route. I hate multiple OR logic.

```
var allObjects = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { MyDate = "3/10/18" },
    new Foo { MyDate = "3/11/18" },
    new Foo { MyDate = "3/12/18" },
    new Foo { MyDate = "3/13/18" },
    new Foo { MyDate = "3/14/18" }
};
var valuesToRemove = new DayOfWeek[]
{ 
    DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday 
};
var list = allObjects.Where   //<-- This is the part that will interest you
( 
    x => Array.IndexOf
    (
        valuesToRemove, 
        Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDate).DayOfWeek
    ) == -1
);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", list));
```

Output:

```
3/12/18
3/13/18
3/14/18
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ILLmd)

Answer (score 0):

This might not help with regard to reusing calculated values in LINQ expressions, but in your specific case, you can rewrite it as:

```
var weekendDays = new [] { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday };

var weekdayObjects = allObjects.Where(x =>
    !weekendDays.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(x.MyDate).DayOfWeek)
).ToList();
```